# Serialize a runnable object

Tags: java, serialization, runnable

Is it possible to serialize a runnable object in java6?
I want to store the runnable object into a file.

If not, is there any other way to achieve this?

I have this class:

```
public abstract class SerializableRunnable implements Serializable, Runnable
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6217172014399079306L;

    @Override
    public abstract void run();

}
```

Then I have another class that container the previous one:

```
public class Action implements Serializable
{
    ...
    private SerializableRunnable m_runnable;

    @Override
    public void Write(DataOutputStream dout) throws IOException
    {
        ...
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        oos.writeObject(m_runnable);
        oos.close();

        byte[] m_runnableBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        dout.writeInt(m_runnableBytes.length);
        dout.write(m_runnableBytes);
    }
...
}
```

The problem is that I get a  **java.io.NotSerializableException** in this line of code:

```
oos.writeObject(m_runnable);
```

Stack trace:

```
java.io.NotSerializableException:
  [r]   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
  [r]   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
  [r]   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
  [r]   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
  [r]   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
  [r]   at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
  [r]   at mypackage.Action.Write(Action.java:52)
```

Runnable creation:

```
EventManager.addAction(new Action(false, EventManager.ON_EVENT_X, 
    new SerializableRunnable()
    {
         @Override
         public void run()
         {
             // Do whatever
         }
    }));
```

Thanks in advance

EDIT: added sample code
EDIT2: added stack trace
EDIT3: added runnable creation

Comment: Yes you can. Make sure your class implements both Runnable and Serializable. You can store an object into file using ObjectOutputStream, and restore using ObjectInputStream. But I would save an object that hold some state or information.

Comment: What should keep you from serializing any object?

Comment: Depending on _why_ you want to store the object, it might be easier to write a `class` to hold only data and serialize that. Then make your `Runnable` use that data class.

Comment: Can you provide the stack trace? Your concrete object of m_runnable might be having fields which are not serializeable.

Comment: A number of notes on your code. 1) there is no need to redeclare `abstract` methods that you have not implemented. 2) always use `try-with-resources`, your example code is a classic case - because `writeObject` throws an exception the `OutputStream` is never closed.

Comment: Is there something about your `SerializableRunnable` class that you're not telling us? Your code does not throw `NotSerializableException` as provided.

Comment: @ominiyo you can try adding `-Dsun.io.serialization.extendedDebugInfo=true` to the java command line. You may be able to see what is causing the issue.

Comment: @KDM What is causing the issue is clearly stated in the exception. The class as actually encountered isn't serializable. Clearly the OP isn't running the code he thinks he is running.

Comment: @omniyo is your `SerializableRunnable` class in its own Java file or a nested class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks all for your comments.

The issue was related to what @KDM said. The class wasn't really SerializableRunnable but an anonymous class and therefore the enclosing class must be serializable too.